# 'Incomplete derivative' having potential only on the side of a cylinder.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, differential-forms, surfaces

Consider the "side of the cylinder" defined by ${x}^{2}+{y}^{2}=1$.

I want to make an 'incomplete derivative' (on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ) but having potential only on the side of the cylinder.

I probably make a closed 1-form only on the side of the cylinder (See (1-7)). 
Perhaps theoretically, if the $\omega $ is a 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ , it will have potential $U$ on the side of cylinder if it is closed on the cylinder (Am I correct?) Here, the potential $U$ is a scalar-valued function on side of cylinder such that,
$$dU = \omega . \tag  {1-1}$$

【My Questions】

> **(1)** Can I make an incomplete derivative (on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$)having potential only on the side of the cylinder? (
>   Can we make a one-form that can define the potential only on the side of the cylinder?)
>   **(2)** Following (1-7) might be the closed 1-form only on the "side of the cylinder" defined by ${x}^{2}+{y}^{2}=1$.
>   $$\omega = - \frac{1}{3} {y}^{3}dx  - (\frac{1}{3}{x}^{3}-x) dy + dz \tag  {1-7}$$
>   **(3)** If so, the (1-7) have a potential on the side of the cylinder?  How can I express $U$ as a formula?

**【Details】** 
Let ${f}_{1}(x,y)$ and ${f}_{2}(x,y)$ be a bivariate scalar-valued function and $\omega$ be a one-form defined by
$$\omega :={f}_{1}(x,y)dx + {f}_{2}(x,y)dy + dz \tag  {1-2}$$

Then,
$$d\omega := \frac{\partial {f}_{1}}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial {f}_{2}}{\partial x} dx\wedge dy \tag  {1-3}$$

Therefore, if there are ${f}_{1}(x,y)$ and ${f}_{2}(x,y)$ satisfies the following equation, the $\omega $ should not be a closed-form on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ but, closed on ${x}^{2} +{y}^{2}=1$
$$\frac{\partial {f}_{1}}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial {f}_{2}}{\partial x} = 0 \ \ , iff\ \  {x}^{2} +{y}^{2}=1 \tag  {1-4}$$

For example, if there are ${f}_{1}(x,y)$ and ${f}_{2}(x,y)$ satisfies followings, then, these will satisfy (1-4).
$$\frac{\partial {f}_{1}}{\partial y} = {y}^{2} \tag  {1-5}$$
$$\frac{\partial {f}_{2}}{\partial x} = {x}^{2}+1 \tag  {1-5'}$$

For example, if we define as follows, these seems to satisfy both (1-5) and(1-5').
$$ {f}_{1} := \frac{1}{3} {y}^{3} \tag  {1-6}$$
$$ {f}_{2} := - \frac{1}{3}{x}^{3} + x \tag  {1-6'}$$
Using (1-6) and(1-6)', 
$$\omega = - \frac{1}{3} {y}^{3}dx  - (\frac{1}{3}{x}^{3}-x) dy + dz \tag  {1-7}$$

and then, 
$$d\omega = ({x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-1) dx\wedge dy \tag  {1-8}$$

This might be closed only on the ${x}^{2}+{y}^{2}=1$.

Is it correct?

**P.S.** I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cylinder is not simply connected, so even if the restriction of $\omega$ to the cylinder is *closed*, it need not be *exact*. There is no issue with $dz$ in your example, of course. But necessary and sufficient for $P(x,y)\,dx + Q(x,y)\,dy$ to be exact on the unit circle is that its integral over the circle evaluate to $0$. Yours does not. The form, restricted to the cylinder, cannot be exact.

**EDIT**: In fact, *every* $1$-form $\omega = P(x,y)\,dx + Q(x,y)\,dy + R(z)\,dz$ will be closed on the cylinder. The best way to convince yourself is to use coordinates $(\theta,z)$ on the cylinder. In these coordinates, any $1$-form $\omega = f(\theta)\,d\theta + g(z)\,dz$ is closed, and you can work much better in these coordinates to determine when it's exact.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.　Is my ω not an exact form on the side of the cylinder but a closed form?